# How to host laravel 5.7 on a shared server

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am failing to make laravel 5.7 work on shared hosting.

I tried to use the following tutorials: 
- https://medium.com/laravel-power-devs/deploy-laravel-projects-on-shared-hosting-2008be6f6f03
- and this one too https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e.

but non of them solved my problem, even all the stackoverflow questions about this same topic didn't help me. Please help., i spent more than 1:30 minutes hours on this till now i havent got any solution.

Comment: change your server.php name to index.php in main folder also take out your public folder file outside except index.php

Answer (score 1):

1. Put contents of `public` folder of your project inside `public_html` of the server
2. Put everything else inside a folder and name it anything you like. for eg- `project_support` and place it in root directory of the server(one level up of `public_html`)
3. Change `require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';` to `require __DIR__.'/../project_support/vendor/autoload.php';` in file index.php in your public_html folder
4. Change `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';` to `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../project_support/bootstrap/app.php';` in file index.php in your public_html folder
5. Configure your `.env` according to you.